# ReactJS project keeps failing to deploy on Railway.app

Tags: reactjs, railway

#11 2.320 npm ERR! code EUSAGE
#11 2.324 npm ERR!
#11 2.324 npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
#11 2.324 npm ERR!
#11 2.324 npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's typescript@5.0.2 does not satisfy typescript@4.9.5
#11 2.324 npm ERR!
#11 2.324 npm ERR! Clean install a project
#11 2.325 npm ERR!
#11 2.325 npm ERR! Usage:
#11 2.325 npm ERR! npm ci
#11 2.325 npm ERR!
#11 2.325 npm ERR! Options:
#11 2.325 npm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
#11 2.325 npm ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global] [--global-style] [--legacy-bundling]
#11 2.325 npm ERR! [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
#11 2.325 npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
#11 2.325 npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
#11 2.325 npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]

#11 2.325 npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
#11 2.325 npm ERR!
#11 2.325 npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
#11 2.325 npm ERR!
#11 2.325 npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info
#11 2.327
#11 2.327 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#11 2.327 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-04-04T18_22_59_141Z-debug-0.log
#11 ERROR: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c npm ci" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

---

> [stage-0  7/10] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/da37dc0a-fecd-49f0-b986-1d998cea339d-/root/npm,target=/root/.npm npm ci:
> #11 2.325 npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
> #11 2.325 npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
> #11 2.325 npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
> #11 2.325 npm ERR!
> #11 2.325 npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
> #11 2.325 npm ERR!
> #11 2.325 npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info
> #11 2.327
> #11 2.327 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> #11 2.327 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-04-04T18_22_59_141Z-debug-0.log

---

### Dockerfile:21

### 19 |     RUN printf '\nPATH=/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH' >> /root/.profile
20 |     COPY . /app/.
21 | >>> RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/da37dc0a-fecd-49f0-b986-1d998cea339d-/root/npm,target=/root/.npm npm ci
22 |
23 |     # build phase

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c npm ci" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Error: Docker build failed

I've tried placing ( "build": "CI=false react-scripts build" ) in the scripts part of my package.json but still nothing (As I've seen this to be the fix to the issue). Has anyone else had this same issue or have any tips for how to avoid this problem in the future?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it with `npm install`. Did you try it? The log clearly mentions it: '*Please update your lock file with npm install before continuing.*'. I'm posting it as an answer, because I don't have enough reputation to post it as a comment, but sometimes we can miss a recommendation and the solution is that obvious.

Comment: I actually did do that but I found the fix! 

Step #1: in package.json -- "start": "serve build -s -n -L -p $PORT"
Step #2: npm i serve

Comment: It's great that it works! You can add it as a solution to help others.